# Color behind rounded edges in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, colors, selector

I have a listview that I have customized to have rounded edges for the list items.  Everything works fine except I get a green color behind each listview item when it is pressed.  It appears to be the same color used for the original button selections. Is there anyway to change this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <corners android:radius="10dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#000000" android:startColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <corners android:radius="10dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" />
    </shape></item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `android:cacheColorHint="#0000"` and `android:listSelector="#0000"` to your ListView